# Image overflowing when using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem I'm having is that the image height will not stay in its container's boundaries.

The the max-width being applied to the image seems to work, however, the max-height doesn't.

HTML

```
<div class="row-layout">
  <div class="artist-image">
    <img >
  </div>
  <div class="artist-image">
    <img >
  </div>
  <div class="artist-image">
    <img >
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.row-layout {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   width: 100%;
   height: 250px;
 }
.artist-image {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-shrink: 0;
   flex-basis: 0;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}
.artist-image > img {
   max-width: 100%;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full code (including the images), so we can see the problem.

Comment: `flex-basis:0` makes no sense. You're just asking it to take 0 width.

Comment: I put your code in a codepen and it seems to work okay: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ramxeo

Comment: I don't want the image to exceed the 'artist-image' div. I want it to sit in the div, with the whole image showing, regardless of the images dimensions.

Comment: Does anyone know why the 'max-height' property on the image doesn't work?

Comment: please note my new (changed) answer + codepen

Comment: The reason `max-height` isn't working on your image is because you're using a percentage value, without specifying a height on the parent: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 2):

NEW (CHANGED) ANSWER:

Define the images as background-images of their containers, center those and choose `background-size: contain`. This will always show the full image in its original proportions, fitted to the size of the container:

```
.x {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/600x400) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Here's the whole thing in a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKzQbK